# jQuery Mobile swipe event also produces tap: how to ignore resulting tap event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, jquery-events

We need to bind to the `swipe` and `tap` events for a DIV. However, the `swipe` event in jQuery Mobile (1.3) also produces a `tap` event. We need to stop swipes from propagating to the tap handler, but `preventDefault` did not work. In other words, we want swipes to only trigger the swipe handler and not trigger the tap handler.

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

`swipe` happens always before `tap`, so try this:

```
var swipped;    
$(element).on('swipe tap',function(evt){
    if(evt.type=='swipe') {
        swipped = true;
        if(evt.swipestart.coords[0]>evt.swipestop.coords[0]){
            console.log('swipe left to right')
        } else {
            console.log('swipe right to left')
        }
    } else {
        if(swipped){ // ignore this tap
            swipped=false;
        } else {
            console.log('tap');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unbind` function on the element that you want to listen to `swipe` event only.

```
$(ele).unbind("tap taphold");
```

Comment: We need to bind to both events for the same element, unfortunately.

Comment: In this case, then I think you should defer the execution of the tap callback after 1 second. If within this 1 second, a swipe is happened, then the callback is dropped, otherwise, it will be fired.

Comment: Appreciate this is three years old... but could you please give us a demonstration of what you mean? You might even get the brownie points for answering the question :)